# How can I run one line of bash shell script as a specific user

Tags: bash, shell, sudo

I have a script I run manually (let's say) `mylogin`. But there's one line that needs to run as user `postgres`.

What is a good way to do that?

It's ok if I get a password prompt. I just need it to work somehow.

Here's what I have so far...

`~/reload_test_data.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

# Here's the part that needs to run as user `postgres`...

sudo su postgres
export PGDATA=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/data && pg_ctl -m fast restart

# And here we should go back to `mylogin`...

cd ~/projects/my_project
echo 'Dropping database'
bundle exec rake db:drop

# More stuff etc...
```

I'm using Mac OS 10.12.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the arguments for sudo is the command so you can do something like:

`sudo -u <user> bash -c "command_1; command_2; etc"`

where `-u <user>` change to your target user